# Using Javascript Window.open

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code so that I use Javascript using window.open to open a url.  This opens a new window as desired, BUT the url is wrong.  It adds the domain url to the beginning of it.  Does anyone know how I would fix this?  It has to use javascript.

```
&TeledoccLogo = "<a onclick=""javascript:window.open('www.teladocc.com/');iAddClickStat('Benefits_Teladocc_Link');return false;"" href='#'>
```

URL it takes me to:
https://finder-t2.int.ps.nbc.com/psp/ps/EMPLOYEE/EMPL/h/www.teladocc.com/pnc

Comment: try adding the full url with http://, 
   http://www.teladocc.com

Comment: that is the full url.  www.teladocc.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because this isn't a full URL:

```
www.teladocc.com
```

It's a *relative* URL.  The browser has no way of knowing the difference between `www.teladocc.com` and, say, `index.html`.

If you did this:

```
window.open('index.html')
```

Then you wouldn't really expect to go to `http://index.html`, would you?

Use a fully-qualified URL:

```
window.open('http://www.teladocc.com/pnc')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the http protocol to the url, like this:

```
&TeledoccLogo = "<a onclick=""javascript:window.open('http://www.teladocc.com/pnc');iAddClickStat('Benefits_Teladocc_Link');return false;"" href='#'>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `http://` to the link in your window.open. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLdpbod2/) demo.

This one will replace the current URL:

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://google.com');">Demo</button>
```

This one will open the URL and append:

```
<button onclick="window.open('google.com');">Demo 2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the protocol in your call.

```
&TeledoccLogo = "<a onclick=""javascript:window.open('http://www.teladocc.com/pnc');iAddClickStat('Benefits_Teladocc_Link');return false;"" href='#'>
```